# Basic json and pandas DataFrame build

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I am very new to python and learning my way up. My task is to crawl data from web and filing xlsx data using json and pandas (and etc..). I am researching through some examples of modifing json dic to pandas DataFrame, and I cant seem to find the one that I need.

Im gussing this would be very basic, but help me out.

so below is my code

```
js ='{"startDate":"2017-01-01","endDate":"2017-10-31","timeUnit":"month","results":
[{"title":"fruit","keywords":["apple","banana"],"data":
[{"period":"2017-01-01","ratio":19.35608},
{"period":"2017-02-01","ratio":17.33902},
{"period":"2017-03-01","ratio":22.30411},
{"period":"2017-04-01","ratio":20.94646},
{"period":"2017-05-01","ratio":23.8557},
{"period":"2017-06-01","ratio":22.38169},
{"period":"2017-07-01","ratio":27.38557},
{"period":"2017-08-01","ratio":19.16214},
{"period":"2017-09-01","ratio":32.07913},
{"period":"2017-10-01","ratio":41.89293}]},
{"title":"veg","keywords":["carrot","onion"],"data":
[{"period":"2017-01-01","ratio":100.0},
{"period":"2017-02-01","ratio":80.41117},
{"period":"2017-03-01","ratio":89.29402},
{"period":"2017-04-01","ratio":74.32118},
{"period":"2017-05-01","ratio":69.82156},
{"period":"2017-06-01","ratio":66.52444},
{"period":"2017-07-01","ratio":67.84328},
{"period":"2017-08-01","ratio":74.43754},
{"period":"2017-09-01","ratio":65.82621},
{"period":"2017-10-01","ratio":65.55469}]}]}'
```

And I have tried below

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json_normalize(js), orient='columns')
df
```

and

```
df = pd.read_json(js)
results = df['results'].head()
dd = results['data']
results.to_json(orient='split')
```

and

```
data = json.loads(js)
data["results"]
data["startDate"]
data2 = json.loads(data["results"])
data2["data"]
```

And I want my DataFrame to be like below

```
    Date          Fruit       Veg
0  2017-01-01   19.35608     100.0
1  2017-02-01   17.33902     80.41117
2  2017-03-01   22.30411     89.29402
3  2017-04-01   20.94646     74.32118
4  2017-05-01   23.8557      69.82156
```

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------edit

The code (from @COLDSPEED) worked perfect until one point. I use your code to my new crawler "[Crawler: Combining DataFrame per each loop Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47619920/crawler-combining-dataframe-per-each-loop-python)" and it ran perfectly until my DNA reached to 170. The error message is below

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2441             try:
-> 2442                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2443             except KeyError:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'period'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-2a1de403b285> in <module>()
     47         d = json.loads(js)
     48         lst = [pd.DataFrame.from_dict(r['data']).set_index('period').rename(columns={'ratio' : r['title']})
---> 49            for r in d['results']]
     50         df = pd.concat(lst, 1)
     51         dfdfdf = Data.join(df)

<ipython-input-30-2a1de403b285> in <listcomp>(.0)
     47         d = json.loads(js)
     48         lst = [pd.DataFrame.from_dict(r['data']).set_index('period').rename(columns={'ratio' : r['title']})
---> 49            for r in d['results']]
     50         df = pd.concat(lst, 1)
     51         dfdfdf = Data.join(df)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in set_index(self, keys, drop, append, inplace, verify_integrity)
   2828                 names.append(None)
   2829             else:
-> 2830                 level = frame[col]._values
   2831                 names.append(col)
   2832                 if drop:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1962             return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
   1963         else:
-> 1964             return self._getitem_column(key)
   1965 
   1966     def _getitem_column(self, key):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _getitem_column(self, key)
   1969         # get column
   1970         if self.columns.is_unique:
-> 1971             return self._get_item_cache(key)
   1972 
   1973         # duplicate columns & possible reduce dimensionality

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in _get_item_cache(self, item)
   1643         res = cache.get(item)
   1644         if res is None:
-> 1645             values = self._data.get(item)
   1646             res = self._box_item_values(item, values)
   1647             cache[item] = res

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py in get(self, item, fastpath)
   3588 
   3589             if not isnull(item):
-> 3590                 loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
   3591             else:
   3592                 indexer = np.arange(len(self.items))[isnull(self.items)]

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2442                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2443             except KeyError:
-> 2444                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2445 
   2446         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'period'
```

I found out that if the js has no value in 'data' which shows below. (please disregard the Korean title)

```
{"startDate":"2016-01-01","endDate":"2017-12-03","timeUnit":"date","results":[{"title":"황금뿔나팔버섯","keywords":["황금뿔나팔버섯"],"data":[]}]}
```

So I want to check if there is 'data' before using your code. please take a look below and tell me what is wrong with it please.

```
if ([pd.DataFrame.from_dict(r['data']) for r in d['results']] == []):
    #want to put only the column name as 'title' and move on
else:
    lst = [pd.DataFrame.from_dict(r['data']).set_index('period').rename(columns={'ratio' : r['title']})
       for r in d['results']]
    df = pd.concat(lst, 1)
```

Comment: please update the question with your code and what you tried.

Comment: That isn't code, it's a string of data. Please give an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempts and the issue.

Comment: @ddor254  sorry. 
I found to normalize the data to make columns and it keeps giving me errors. Also I have tired to normalize myself like above, but it seems not making sense at all.

Comment: @roganjosh I tried to normalize it and kept showing errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your structure is consistent, use a list comprehension and then concatenate -

```
import json

d = json.loads(js)
lst = [
   pd.DataFrame.from_dict(r['data'])\
         .set_index('period').rename(columns={'ratio' : r['title']})

   for r in d['results']
]

df = pd.concat(lst, 1)
df

               fruit        veg
period                         
2017-01-01  19.35608  100.00000
2017-02-01  17.33902   80.41117
2017-03-01  22.30411   89.29402
2017-04-01  20.94646   74.32118
2017-05-01  23.85570   69.82156
2017-06-01  22.38169   66.52444
2017-07-01  27.38557   67.84328
2017-08-01  19.16214   74.43754
2017-09-01  32.07913   65.82621
2017-10-01  41.89293   65.55469
```

Comment: Thank you so much. My next step was to make period as index and its already solved.

Comment: @kang Yw ;-) Feel free to also vote on the answer as you deem fit. Cheers.

Comment: @COLDSPEED Oh one more thing. What would be the code for from DataFrame to Dictionary just like js above? is there deconcatenate for pandas?

Comment: @kang You can use `df.to_json('file.json')`

Comment: @COLDSPEED I just want to check one last thing on this. So lets say my "{"period":"2017-03-01","ratio":89.29402}" data is missing from veg in 'js' and would my pd.concat(lst, 1) still say "2017-03-01  22.30411   NaN"??? I need all values to concat even though one is missing.

Comment: @kang I think so, yes.

Comment: @COLDSPEED Your code worked perfectly until the error message above (I added error message above). The error only occur in a specific 'js'.

Comment: @COLDSPEED I found out that the error occurs because there is no data in certain 'js'. If my 'js' (sometimes there will be no value at all) is "'{"startDate":"2016-01-01","endDate":"2017-12-03","timeUnit":"date","results":[{"title":"nodata","keywords":["nodata"],"data":[]}]}'", how can I only name the column as 'title' and not put any period data?

Comment: @COLDSPEED I'm sorry for all these mass....... I elaborated my question on this link. "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47628924/json-to-dataframe-converstion-issues" Thanks.